# Calculating execution time of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I have this algorithm:

```
S(n)
  if n=1 then return(0)
  else
    S(n/3)
    x <- 0
    while x<= 3n^3 do
       x <- x+3
    S(n/3)
```

Is `2 * T(n/3) + n^3` the recurrence relation?

Is `T(n) = O(n^3)` the execution time?

Answer (score 2):

The recurrence expression is correct. The time complexity of the algorithm is `O(n^3)`.

The recurrence stops at `T(1)`.

Running an example for `n = 27` helps deriving a general expression:

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/3)+n^3 =
= 2*(2*T(n/9)+(n/3)^3)+n^3 =
= 2*(2*(2*T(n/27)+(n/9)^3)+(n/3)^3)+n^3 =
= ... =
= 2*(2*2*T(n/27)+2*(n/9)^3+(n/3)^3)+n^3 =
= 2*2*2*T(n/27)+2*2*(n/9)^3+2*(n/3)^3+n^3
```

From this example we can see that the general expression is given by:

[image]

Which is equivalent to:

[image]

Which, in turn, can be solved to the following closed form:

[image]

The dominating term in this expression is `(1/25)*27n^3` (`2^(log_3(n))` is `O(n)`, you can think of it as `2^(log(n)*(1/log(3)))`; dropping the constant `1/log(3)` gives `2^log(n) = n`), thus, the recurrence is `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
2 * T(n/3) + n^3
```

Yes, I think this is a correct recurrence relation.

Time complexity:

```
while x<= 3n^3 do
       x <- x+3
```

This has a Time complexity of O(n^3). Also, at each step, the function calls itself twice with 1/3rd n. So the series shall be

```
n, n/3, n/9, ...
```

The total complexity after adding each depth

```
n^3 + 2/27 * (n^3) + 4/243 * (n^3)...
```

This series is bounded by `k*n^3` where `k` is a constant.

> Proof: if it is considered as a GP with a factor of 1/2, then the sum
>   becomes 2*n^3. Now we can see that at each step, the factor is
>   continuously decreasing and is less than half. Hence the upper bound is less than 2*n^3.

So in my opinion the complexity = O(n^3).